# How to Create an Infrared Filter Effect in C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, windows-phone-8, filtering

I recently came across some very cool pictures from a google image search for infrared, and I'd like to try out some pixel manipulation to create this effect. I do have experience with pixel manipulation, usually with just going from start to end of an image, extracting the argb values, manipulating them, then recreating the pixel and placing it back into the image or a copy. I suppose my question is, how can I find out how to manipulate the rgb values to create such an effect from a regular image?

I would probably be using something of the following to extract argb values from the pixel data while looping through the image's pixels

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x, ++index)
            {
                uint currentPixel = sourcePixels[index]; // get the current pixel

                uint alpha = (currentPixel & 0xff000000) >> 24; // alpha component
                uint red = (currentPixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16; // red color component
                uint green = (currentPixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8; // green color component
                uint blue = currentPixel & 0x000000ff; // blue color component

                //Modify pixel values

                uint newPixel = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue; // reassembling each component back into a pixel

                targetPixels[index] = newPixel; // assign the newPixel to the equivalent location in the output image

            }
```

Edit: Sample Picture Below

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: You haven't said what sort of effect. Infrared information is not available so that is not a description.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant change the pixels so they look like they came from an infrared picture. I have attached a sample picture to my orginal post.

Comment: This is simply a form of false-colour. Use any colur substitution formula/table you like. Again, you're not going to get a real infrared image.

Comment: I know, I'm just looking to try a similar effect. Can you recommend any formulas or values, or possible links with samples/tutorials? I've come across several other types of effects, but not this one I particular.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the effect of infrared shooting is difficult for reproducing without understanding how different objects on the photo reflect or absorb infrared light. Therein lays the problem that doesn’t allow us to create the universal infrared filter. Although there are some workarounds. We know that leafs and grass usually reflect infrared light more than other objects. Thus, the main objective should be manipulation with a green color (or other color if you want some additional effects).

[AForge.Imaging](https://code.google.com/p/aforge/) is an open-source .NET library, which might be a good starting point. It provides a variety of [filters](https://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSources%2FImaging%2FFilters) and you can easily check how each of them was implemented. You can also check [examples](https://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSamples%2FImaging%2FFiltersDemo) which come within the project. Another option is to look at the project on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9727/Image-Processing-Lab-in-C). I wrote a bit of code in order to show how to use some filters.

```
public static class ImageProcessing
{
     public static Bitmap Process(Bitmap image, IFilter filter)
     {
         return filter.Apply(image);
     }

     public static Bitmap Process(string path, IFilter filter)
     {
         var image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path);
         return filter.Apply(image);
     }

     public static Bitmap Process(string path, IEnumerable<IFilter> filters)
     {
         var image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path);
         foreach (var filter in filters)
         {
             Bitmap tempImage = filter.Apply(image);
             image.Dispose();
             image = tempImage;
         }
         return image;
     }
}
```

### Original image (test.jpg)

[image]

### Application of hue modifier

```
ImageProcessing.Process("test.jpg", new HueModifier(30))
               .Save("result_1.jpg");
```

### Result of hue modifier (result_1.jpg)

[image]

### Application of saturation correction

```
ImageProcessing.Process("test.jpg", new SaturationCorrection(0.35f))
               .Save("result_2.jpg");
```

### Result of saturation correction (result_2.jpg)

[image]

### Application of filter chain

```
ImageProcessing.Process("test.jpg"
            ,new List<IFilter>() {
                                  new BrightnessCorrection(), 
                                  new SaturationCorrection(0.1f), 
                                  new HueModifier(300)})
            .Save("result_3.jpg");
```

### Result of filter chain (result_3.jpg)

[image]